paste the value of the first cell in an edited row
This is a "change log" function that adds a new row describing each edit to sheet "Edit Log". How can I also notate the value of the first column in the edited row?
function onEdit(e) {
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var user = e.user;
  var cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var oldValue = e.oldValue;
  var newValue = e.value;
  var sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();

  var logSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Edit Log");

  if (logSheet == null) {
    logSheet = e.source.insertSheet("Edit Log");
    logSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "User", "Cell", "Old Value", "New Value", "Sheet Name"]);
  }
  // only paste changes if they come from the sheet Master Census
  if (sheetName == "Master Census") {

    logSheet.appendRow([timestamp, user, cell, oldValue, newValue, sheetName]); 

  } else {
    return
  }

}

I'd like to make:
var member = ...

function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Master Census") {
    var lsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Edit Log");
    if (!lsh) {
      lsh = e.source.insertSheet("Edit Log");
      lsh.appendRow(["Timestamp", "User", "Cell", "Old Value", "New Value", "First Col of Edited Row"]);
    }
    lsh.getRange(lsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 6).setValues([[new Date(), e.user, e.range.getA1Notation(), e.oldValue, e.value, sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).getValue()]]);
  }
}

Or you could eliminate the getA1Notation function with
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Master Census") {
    var lsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Edit Log");
    if (!lsh) {
      lsh = e.source.insertSheet("Edit Log");
      lsh.appendRow(["Timestamp", "User", "row", "col", "Old Value", "New Value", "First Col of Edited Row"]);
    }
    lsh.getRange(lsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 7).setValues([[new Date(), e.user, e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart, e.oldValue, e.value, sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).getValue()]]);
  }
}


Much better than mine.  Appreciate the approach

Do you think you could spell this out for me? I see you have one line handling all the needed changes but my understanding is low enough to keep losing track of what values are being produced by each.


New constants row and firstColumnValue

Moved the if (sheetName == "Master Census") to the beginning of the script so it doesn't do anything if there is no edit to record.


function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const sheetName = sheet.getName();

  // only do anything more if edit comes from sheet Master Census
  if (sheetName == "Master Census") {
    const user = e.user;
    const oldValue = e.oldValue;
    const newValue = e.value;
    const timestamp = new Date();
    const cell = range.getA1Notation();
    const row = range.getRow(); 
    const firstColumnValue = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
    const logSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Edit Log");

    if (logSheet == null) {
      logSheet = ss.insertSheet("Edit Log");
      logSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "User", "Cell", "Old Value", "New Value", "Sheet Name", "Value in Column 1"]);
    }

    logSheet.appendRow([timestamp, user, cell, oldValue, newValue, sheetName, firstColumnValue]); 
    } 
}


this is very helpful for a beginner because you list out all the involved constants. I appreciate that. I've found though that when using this it will only write changes if I'm the user making the change. Another user editing the Master Census sheet doesn't cause this function to execute.

Does the user have full edit permissions for the spreadsheet or only for the "Master Census" sheet?  If they don't have edit permissions for the "Edit Log" sheet it may be failing. Check the event log for the script to see if there are any error messages.

If you are trying to write to a protected sheet. Use an installable trigger (instead of simple trigger) so it runs as the user that created it
